# Fee field must not be blank

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

In this trigger apex, I want to give error when **Fee_paid__c** field must not be blank. We can throw the error as **"Please enter amount"**

**I tried above code**

```
trigger Not_Negative on Student__c (before insert) {
    for(Student__c x: trigger.new){
        if(x.Fee_paid__c < 0 && !(isblank(x.Fee_paid__c))){
            x.Fee_paid__c.adderror('Please enter amount');
        }
    }
}
```

**The above image contains error message that i had getting error**
[image: Error msg]

Please suggest me how to implement the condition. Thank you !

Comment: Hi Hari, `!(isblank(x.Fee_paid__c)) ` is not valid . Please check `x.Fee_paid__c!=null `condition

Comment: Problem is solved, but if Fee_paid__c field leaves blank then also record was get saved with blank field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the if condition as below. I hope the condition should be `||` instead of `&&`

```
 if(x.Fee_paid__c < 0 || x.Fee_paid__c==null ){
            x.Fee_paid__c.adderror('Please enter amount');
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Problem solved